# Getting error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To get the average of rows of sold items of in each distribution branch, I used this query:

```
SELECT 
    dc.dcname, AVG(si.RowOrder) AS Average
FROM
    gnr.tblDC dc
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleHdr sh ON sh.DCRef = dc.id
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleItm si ON si.HdrRef = sh.id
WHERE 
    sh.Year = 2023
    AND sh.exitref IS NOT NULL
    AND sh.SaleDate BETWEEN '2023/01/01' AND '2023/10/30'
GROUP BY 
    dc.DCName
```

But this query is not accurate, I compare it by manually calculation I se the right answer is 3.82 but query return 4.42 as average rows of orders. The correct way is to use a count in average like

```
SELECT 
    dc.dcname, AVG(count(si.RowOrder)) AS Average
FROM 
    gnr.tblDC dc
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleHdr sh ON sh.DCRef = dc.id
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleItm si ON si.HdrRef = sh.id
WHERE 
    sh.Year = 2023
    AND sh.exitref IS NOT NULL
    AND sh.SaleDate BETWEEN '2023/01/01' AND '2023/10/30'
GROUP BY 
    dc.DCName
```

In this second query, I get an error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Update :

**gnr.tbldc:**

```
ID  DCCode  DCName
------------------------
0   0        HQ
1   14       Guilan
9   31       Esfahan
```

**sle.tblSaleHdr**

```
      ID    SaleNo  OrderRef    ExitRef SaleDate    TotalAmount UserRef ChangeDate  Year    DCRef   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
650135799   15727   650127693   1008    2023/10/10  48093773.00 1334    2023/10/18  2023    9   
650135800   15728   650127694   1009    2023/10/10  22845240.00 1334    2023/10/18  2023    9
```

**sle.tblSaleItm**

```
      ID      HdrRef    RowOrder    GoodsRef    UnitRef UnitCapasity    UnitQty TotalQty    AmountNut   Discount    Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
650430979   650135799   1   328 0   50.000  1.000   50.000  10169500.00 1655500.00  11825000.00 
650430980   650135799   2   329 0   50.000  1.000   50.000  10169500.00 1655500.00  11825000.00 
650430981   650135799   3   769 0   20.000  1.000   20.000  1651200.00  268800.00   1920000.00  
650430982   650135799   4   480 0   20.000  1.000   20.000  1651200.00  268800.00   1920000.00  
650430983   650135799   5   481 0   20.000  1.000   20.000  1651200.00  268800.00   1920000.00  
650430984   650135799   6   504 0   96.000  1.000   96.000  4499973.00  499995.00   4999968.00  
650430985   650135799   7   832 0   24.000  1.000   24.000  1925280.00  366720.00   2292000.00  
650430986   650135799   8   191 0   40.000  1.000   40.000  2413920.00  154080.00   2568000.00  
650430987   650135799   9   785 0   36.000  1.000   36.000  1099800.00  70200.00    1170000.00  
650430988   650135799   10  765 0   36.000  1.000   36.000  3246948.00  207252.00   3454200.00  
650430989   650135799   11  1072    0   48.000  1.000   48.000  1987632.00  323568.00   2311200.00  
650430990   650135799   12  722 0   36.000  1.000   36.000  1529910.00  189090.00   1719000.00  
650430991   650135799   13  409 0   24.000  1.000   24.000  1971120.00  320880.00   2292000.00  
650430992   650135799   14  145 0   36.000  1.000   36.000  1553580.00  172620.00   1726200.00  
650430993   650135799   15  1081    0   36.000  1.000   36.000  1553580.00  172620.00   1726200.00  
650430994   650135799   16  503 0   90.000  1.000   90.000  1019430.00  65070.00    1084500.00  
650430995   650135800   1   1168    0   48.000  5.000   240.000 14120160.00 1227840.00  15348000.00 
650430996   650135800   2   1152    0   48.000  5.000   240.000 8725080.00  862920.00   9588000.00
```

Comment: You wrap the first aggregate in a subquery and then run the average on the aggerated field

Comment: `AVG(count(si.RowOrder))` doesn't really make sense. You wanted the average number of items per transactions in a distribution branch?

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks for your comment. Yes. if an order has 2 row of cargos it returns 1.5 (1+2/2) instead of (2/1  ) I mean it seems the first query make a sum of rows and divide it to the count of rows. this wrong it should count the row then divide it to the count of orders.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results in addition to your query. Actual data is by far the best way to communicate the intentions behind a query.

Comment: @RSA, try this please note I have not tested as there is no data and table script provided.

`SUM(si.RowOrder) / COUNT(si.RowOrder)`

calculate the sum of si.RowOrder for each distribution branch, divide it by the count of rows, and provide the average as you described.

Comment: this should do it `count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct sh.id) as Average`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan it is not correct way, if there is 2 orders 1st one with 9 rows and 2nd one with 2 rows your formula answer will be (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1+2)/2 = 48/11=4.36 instead of 11 (rows)/2(orders)=5.5.

Comment: @Squirrel it is right its worked. thank you so much. writhe it in answer plus to approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instead

```
count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct sh.id)
```

Multiply by 1.0 is to convert the integer to decimal before division or you will just get integer as the result

```
SELECT 
    dc.dcname, 
    count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct sh.id) AS Average
FROM 
    gnr.tblDC dc
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleHdr sh ON sh.DCRef = dc.id
INNER JOIN 
    sle.tblSaleItm si ON si.HdrRef = sh.id
WHERE 
    sh.Year = 2023
    AND sh.exitref IS NOT NULL
    AND sh.SaleDate BETWEEN '2023/01/01' AND '2023/10/30'
GROUP BY 
    dc.DCName
```